# Como resolver este erro com o componente Drawer do Materialui

Tags: react

Estou tentando utilizar o drawer do material ui, porém está retornando o seguinte erro quando o gulp vai processa-lo:

> Unexpected token (15:17) handleToggle = () => this.setState({open:
>   !this.state.open})

O errro aponta para o "=" após "hanbleToggle"

O código é o seguinte:

> import React from 'react';
>   import Drawer from 'material-ui/Drawer';
>   import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';
>   import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
>
> export default class DrawerSimpleExample extends React.Component {
>
> ```
> constructor(props) {
>
>     super(props);
>     this.state = {open: false};
>
> }
>
> handleToggle = () => this.setState({open: !this.state.open});
>
> render() {
>     return (
>         <div>
>             <RaisedButton
>                 label="Toggle Drawer"
>                 onTouchTap={this.handleToggle}
>             />
>             <Drawer open={this.state.open}>
>                 <MenuItem>Menu Item</MenuItem>
>                 <MenuItem>Menu Item 2</MenuItem>
>             </Drawer>
>         </div>
>     );
> } }
> ```

Minha task de browserify e babel no gulp:

> gulp.task('browserify', function() {
>
> ```
> browserify({
>     entries: './app/app.js',
>     extensions: config.extensions,
>     debug: config.debug
> })
>     .transform(babelify,{presets: ["es2015", "react"]})
>     .bundle()
>     .pipe(source(config.bundleConfigs.outputName))
>     .pipe(gulp.dest(config.bundleConfigs.dest));
> ```
>
> });

Comment: Bom, o problema era que eu precisava adicinar o babel stage-0. Consegui solucionar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro que te está a dar é porque ainda não é possivel "officialmente" implementar propriedades em Classes.

Isso chama-se [Class Properties e está a ser discutido](https://github.com/jeffmo/es-class-public-fields) para ser incorporado na ES7. Neste momento esta funcionalidade está na fase 2.

Ou seja, voltado à tua pergunta, quando tens

```
class DrawerSimpleExample extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {open: false};

    }

    handleToggle = () => this.setState({open: !this.state.open});
}
```

`handleToggle =` é uma declaração ilegal dentro da classe, pois não faz parte da ECMAScript. A única coisa que é possivel em ES6 é criar métodos, e adicionar propriedades como `handleToggle` depois da declaração da classe com

```
DrawerSimpleExample.prototype.handleToggle = () => DrawerSimpleExample.setState({open: !DrawerSimpleExample.state.open});
```

#### Solução:

usar o modulo [`stage-o` da Babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-0/) ([como apontaste](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/140286/como-resolver-este-erro-com-o-componente-drawer-do-materialui#comment290710_140286)) para converter código "do futuro" em código que o Node/webpack saibam usar.